# c++ pointers and string of characters

Tags: c++

am a bit confused about something in string of characters and pointers regarding c++ language ..

well, i came to know that a name of an array of characters is actually the address of it's first element and i also know that The cout object assumes that the address of a char is the address of a string, so it prints the character at that address and then continues printing characters until it runs into the null character (\0).

but here is the interesting part i tried this code in codeblocks

```
char arr[10]="bear";    
cout <<&arr<<endl;  // trying to find the address of the whole string 
cout<<(int *)arr<<endl; // another way of finding the address of the string 
cout<<(int *)arr[0]<<endl;  // trying to find the address of the first element
```

what came on the screen was as follows

0x22fef6,
0x22fef6,
              (0x62) <<<< My question is , what the heck is that? .. If the arrayname holds the address of the first element , shouldn't the first element address be " 0x22fef6 " ???????????????????

Comment: `cout<<(int *)arr[0]<<endl;  // trying to find the address of the first element ` You probably meant to say `cout<<(int *)&arr[0]<<endl;`to achieve this.

Comment: As a point of style mostly: 1) The array is of chars, so you're doing less needless type conversions if you cast to char* instead of int* 2) You should remove 10 from the brackets, your array contains 5 characters (4 letters + the null character), so by doing this you are over-sizing the array. Furthermore the compiler will size the array for you (with empty []) even if you change "bear" to "grizzlybear", so you're really just adding redundant information to your code you will have to update in multiple places if you make changes later-on.

Comment: Also your comment, "// another way of finding the address of the string" is somewhat untrue, or at least misleading. All the pointer values are the same, however their types are different. If you cast to a char* you have a pointer to a char, not a pointer to an array of chars; if you cast to int* you have a pointer to an int, not a pointer to an array of ints (however doing this breaks strict aliasing and is technically undefined). The main difference here is size of the object being pointed to and how pointer arithmetic and implicit conversions will behave from the resulting expression.

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` operator does not return an address but dereferences the pointer at the given offset.

You could write an equivalent to the `[]` operator as follows:

```
char arr[10] = "bear";
char c = *(arr+0); // == arr[0] == 'b'
```

That is, you take the pointer `arr`, increase it by 0 `char` and then dereferences it to get it's value.

```
char arr[10]="bear";    
cout <<&arr<<endl;
cout<<(int *)arr<<endl;
cout<<(int *)(arr+0)<<endl; // increases the address by 0
cout<<(int *)(&arr[0])<<endl; // the address of the value at index 0
```

This would do what you have expected it to do.

Answer (score 0):

`arr[0]` equals `*(arr + 0)`; you dereference the pointer and obtain the value it holds. To get what you want you need to reference the element, like `&arr[0]`.

Comment: thanks alot :) ... that was extremely  helpful i forgot to put the "&" symbol ;)